# Which Minecraft Java version first included the Ender Dragon?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've tried Googling for the answer, but all the answers are for Pocket Edition (1.0) or obviously wrong (1.9). The answer doesn't even seem to appear on the Fandom wiki.

What was the first version (beta or release) that contained the Ender Dragon as a boss you could fight?

Comment: 1.9 is also correct, since it first had the enderdragon fight as we know it now

Answer (score 27):

Actually, both 1.0 and *Beta* 1.9 are correct.

Ender Dragon was first implemented in Minecraft version Beta 1.9 - which is Release 1.0.0. Yes, you read that right. Release 1.0.0 was initially named Beta 1.9.

At some point Mojang decided to change the version number to 1.0.0, though during beta phase the version number was Beta 1.9, so every pre-release version of 1.0.0 is tagged as Beta 1.9.

You can check more information on [Ender Dragon's history section](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Ender_Dragon#History) and [Java Edition 1.0.0](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Java_Edition_1.0.0), and first ever version that has ender dragon [Beta 1.9 Prerelease 4](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Java_Edition_Beta_1.9_Prerelease_4) (every link is linked to fandom).

Comment: This is not new. I remember the numbering also reset on the transition from Alpha to Beta. In general, I think each development phase had its own separate numbering scheme.